# How to split a string on a 'dot' if, and only if, the preceding and following char is not a 'dot'

Tags: java, regex

Given the following string:

```
"foo.bar.baz"
```

it can be split on the 'dot' easily enough using Java String split:

```
split("foo.bar.baz", "\.")
```

However, if I want to conserve the dot if it is immediately followed by another dot, what is the regex expression:

```
"foo.bar.baz..raz..daz.faz" → "foo" "bar" "baz..raz..daz" "faz"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This regex would work:

```
s.split("(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)");
```

The idea is to use negative lookahead to only split at `"."` which is not followed or preceded by another dot.

Comment: @user3231690 what is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: ok, got it to work, thanks. I needed to use only a single \ rather than \\. Many thanks, really appreciate your assistance on this!

Comment: @user3231690 If you're doing it in Java as a string literal to `split()`, then you definitely need double backslash. Or did you lie to us about real use?

Comment: @Andreas - 'lie' is an awfully strong word, don't you think? I am using clojure and a Clojure String is just a Java String under the hood. So I assumed that the Clojure split was just a wrapper on the Java split - turns out it must be re-implemented in Clojure as it definitely only needs a single /

Comment: @user3231690 Well, you "lied" when you said Java, since you're actually using Clojure, which has the special regex literal `#"regex"` *and the syntax is convenient because you don't need to double escape your special characters* (quoted from [Regexes in Clojure](http://www.lispcast.com/clojure-regex)). Sure, the regex engine is Java, if Clojure is hosted by Java, but the syntax is different, and syntax matters. You simply stating that you *"needed to use only a single \ rather than \\"* is misleading to other readers, because it is **untrue** for Java, hence my comment about "lying".

Comment: @Andreas - ok whatever. Lying is when someone sets out to deliberately deceive, which I did not. But whatever floats your boat mush.